# Flutter iOS - Firebase Cloud Messaging (FCM) push notifications not received

Tags: ios, flutter, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, apple-push-notifications

Steps I followed:

I uploaded APNs Auth Key on Firebase. (I assume this is for both development and release environments.)

On the Flutter app, I got the iOS APNs token and I generated FCM token as well.

On the Firebase notifications composer, I wanted to send a test notification. So, I added the FCM token. I backgrounded/killed/quit the app. Waited on the lock screen to receive notifications. There is one development entitlement file in the Flutter iOS side.

I followed the steps mentioned here - https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/flutter/client

Not sure what's wrong, but I'm not receiving any test notifications. Can someone please help out?